# How much heteroscedasticity need to be present in order to justify the use of robust standard errors?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, linear-model, residuals, heteroscedasticity

Im trying to figure out if my data is heteroscedastic and if I need to use robust standard errors (Huber-White standard errors). The dataset contains 70 000 rows and 5 columns. Y is a numeric continuous variable, x1 is number of days and x2-x4 are categorical variables with >10 levels each. This plot shows the residuals from the following linear model from R:

```
df1 <- mydata
model1 <- lm(log(Y) ~ log(x1) + x2 + x3 + x4, data=df1)
```

[image: Residuals vs Fitted values]

This is the scale-location plot:
[image: Scale-location plot]

This is a histogram of the residuals of the linear model1:
[image: Histogram of residuals of model1]

The dependent variable Y and the independent variable x1 both follows the exponential distribution, approximately, and are therefore logged to reduce heteroscedasticity in the variance (logging a exponential variable approximately makes it normal).

When I run a Breusch–Pagan test - with bptest(model1) - I get: p-value < 2.2e-16. Its my understanding that bptest might always show significant results when the n is really large, about 70k in my case.
I then ran: `coeftest(model, vcov = vcovHC(model, type = "HC0"))` to get the robust standard error. I then compared the robust standard errors with the regular standard error, those of model1. I ran the test with Welch's t-test by using the code `t.test(dataset of regular SE, dataset of robust SE)` and this test produced the following result:

```
Welch two sample t-test
data: Wald and Norm
t = -1.7426, df = 69.162, p-value = 0.08585
sample mean of x: 0.04493, sample mean of y: 0.07512
```

This result indicates that there is no difference between the mean of the normal standard errors and the mean of the robust standard errors.

My questions are these: Are my thinking about bp-test correct (that it shows significant results if n is high enough)? Do you notice any heteroscedasticity from the Residual vs Fitted value plot? Is my thinking correct about my Welch's t-test?